# Overriding a property name when transforming the object to json

Tags: java, json, groovy, jackson

I'm coding some backend tests for a feature at work and apparently got stuck on something that seems easy to solve on paper but can't figure out how to make it work >.>.

Here's an example of what I'm doing.

This is how I need the JSON to end up looking like:

```
{
    "application.properties.service": {
        "properties": {
            "test": "property"
        }
    }
}
```

These are the 2 Groovy classes I wrote to model that request:

```
class Configuration {

    private ApplicationPropertiesService applicationPropertiesService

    Configuration() {

    }

    @JsonProperty("application.properties.service")
    ApplicationPropertiesService getApplicationPropertiesService() {
        return applicationPropertiesService
    }

    void setApplicationPropertiesService(ApplicationPropertiesService applicationPropertiesService) {
        this.applicationPropertiesService = applicationPropertiesService
    }
}
```

--

```
class ApplicationPropertiesService {

    private Map properties

    ApplicationPropertiesService() {
        this.properties = new HashMap()
    }

    ApplicationPropertiesService(Map properties) {
        this.properties = properties
    }

    Map getProperties() {
        return properties
    }

    void setProperties(Map properties) {
        this.properties = properties
    }

    void addProperty(String key, String value) {
        this.properties.put(key, value)
    }
}
```

Here's the test I'm doing to try it out:

```
@Test
void "test"() {
    ApplicationPropertiesService  appPropServ = new ApplicationPropertiesService()
    appPropServ.addProperty("test", "property")
    Configuration testConfig = new Configuration()
    testConfig.setApplicationPropertiesService(appPropServ)

    println new JsonBuilder(testConfig).toPrettyString()
}
```

But of course what I get in the end is this:

```
{
    "applicationPropertiesService": {
        "properties": {
            "test": "property"
        }
    }
}
```

So what I can't figure out is how to override the name so that when parsing it into a JSON it would be separated by `.` instead of camel case as it is right now. 
From what I've been reading the annotation `@JsonProperty("application.properties.service")` from the `jackson.annotation` package should do exactly what I want but I tried putting it before the getter for the property and then putting it above the property declaration at the start of the class but in both cases it just seems to ignore it.

Am I missing anything?.

Comment: Laucien, can you please check the solution to see if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a `JsonProperty` problem, but because of the code

```
Configuration(ApplicationPropertiesService applicationPropertiesService) {
    this.applicationPropertiesService = applicationPropertiesService
}
```

So there is no default constructor in your `Configuration` which makes jackson cannot create the `Configuration` object. (It uses reflection, and do not know the specific constructor to use. So it uses default constructor).

Try to add

```
Configuration() {

}
```

to `Configuration` class.

---

Update: You should not mix Jackson `ObjectMapper` with Groovy  built in `JsonBuilder`.

```
    ApplicationPropertiesService appPropServ = new ApplicationPropertiesService()
    appPropServ.addProperty("test", "property")
    Configuration testConfig = new Configuration()
    testConfig.setApplicationPropertiesService(appPropServ)
     println new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(testConfig)
```

Output:

```
{"application.properties.service":{"properties":{"test":"property"}}}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the idea. I added the empty constructor and removed the other one (since I probably will always be creating it empty then adding the stuff I need anyway) but I'm still getting the same results. Tried putting the `@JsonProperty` at the `get` and also at the top when I define the property and no luck. I updated my original post to reflect the new changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking a groovy based solution, isn't it simple? ***code is data, data is code.***

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def json = new JsonBuilder()
json.'application.properties.service' {
  properties {
    test 'property'
  }
}

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString())

assert '{"application.properties.service":{"properties":{"test":"property"}}}'  == json.toString()
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/6rBL3e)</kbd>

Comment: Hey thanks for the idea!. I honestly didn't know I could try something like that. This code goes into an automation test framework and will support a feature we'll be expanding on in the near future (more data points in that endpoint) so I'm trying to make it more object-based and expandable as possible but if I can't figure out my current issue then I'll definitely go that route haha. Thanks :D.

Comment: @Laucien, Sure. But groovy is object oriented. `json` is object of `JsobBuilder`. Appreciate up vote for helpful answerer & accept answer if you think that is the best one.